# Incrementing a python list by an amount mod x_i, where x_i depends on the position

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, modulo

I have two lists of equal length.
I am incrementing list1 by an amount, but each entry has to be modded by the corresponding entry in list2.

What I am doing is:

```
for ii in range(len(list1)):
    list1[ii] = (list1[ii]+val) % list2[ii]
```

Is there a better way (maybe using numpy)? I could not find any. These lists are very long, so performance is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to reduce the amount of indexing involved:

```
for ii, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
    list1[ii] = (a + val) % b
```

That said, you're probably better off just using a list comprehension to avoid the need for the index entirely, so you can drop `enumerate` and use only `zip`, which makes for cleaner looking code (and faster code to boot):

```
# Creates a new list and rebinds list1 to it:
list1 = [(a + val) % b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]

# Or if list1 *must* be modified in place, slice assignment can do that:
list1[:] = [(a + val) % b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Note that in both examples I renamed your `list` to `list1`, because name shadowing the `list` constructor is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: absolutely, I renamed my list to list1, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using numpy

```
import numpy as np
numpy_list1 = np.array(list1)
numpy_list2 = np.array(list2)

mod_values1 = np.mod(numpy_list1 + val, numpy_list2) 
mod_values2 = np.remainder(numpy_list1 + val, numpy_list2)
mod_values3 = (numpy_list1 + val) % numpy_list2
```

All three give the same results. Documentation for [first](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) and [second](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.remainder.html) is here. The third method was suggested by [Shadow Ranger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) in the comments.

Comment: You forgot about adding `val`, and you don't actually need to use `np.mod`, you could just do `mod_values = (numpy_list1 + val) % numpy_list2`.

Comment: Right! I forgot that. Thanks. Regarding, using `%`, nice. I didn't know that. I'll check it once and update the answer. Thanks!